# Estimate ec2 instance for web application

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io, nestjs

I have been building a web application for 50k users. My application will include:

- APIs + Socket server: NestJS + SocketIO
- Database server: MySQL
- Frontend server: ReactJS

I'm going to choose EC2 instances for those. Could you help me to choose appropriate instances for each server (eg. t2.xlarge or ...)? My application will have 3 environments: develop, staging & production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can provide the information you seek.

Every application is different. Some apps are compute-intensive (eg video transcoding), some are memory-intensive (eg data manipulation) and some are network-intensive (eg video chat). Also, the way users interact with apps are different with each app.

The only way you will know the "appropriate instances for each server" is to **setup a test platform**, select a particular server configuration, then **simulate typical usage** of your application with the desired number of users (eg 50k). **Monitor** each server (CPU, RAM) and find any bottlenecks. Then, adjust instance type and app configurations, and test again.

Yes, it's a lot of work, but that's the only way you'll really know what system sizes and configurations are required. Or, of course, you can simply get *real* users on your app, monitor it very closely and make changes on-the-fly.